# C# Number guessing game being really weird or I am blind..?

Tags: c#

Please tell me what's going on! I don't understand why this is happening... It's running through the loop three times for some reason and not working as expected at all. I don't get this at all...

My Code

[image]

The results...
[image]

Comment: Please include code _in the question_ along with the expected behavior and the observed behavior. Don't make it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Might want to tone the language down in the things before posting the code..

Comment: I think you need `ReadLine` instead of `Read`

Comment: @EJoshuaS I was so hoping that would link to an image saying "don't post images of code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've written `Console.Read()` rather than `Console.ReadLine()`

This means every *character* you type into the console will cause the loop to run, including the characters that make up new lines when you press Enter

Even more confusingly, char '2' is actually 32 numerically, whereas newline/carriage return is 10/13 respectively so if the game is thinking of 25, and you type `22\n` it will come through as 3 guesses and the game will say "too high", "too high", "too low" (32, 32, 10)

Plus, if you type A in, the program will treat it as 65.. But it's a nice intro to the ASCII table  :)

Swap it out for `ReadLine` so that you can type multiple characters and only run the loop when you press Enter. (ReadLine only returns a value when you press enter/return)

Also consider putting some error handling in; as is your code will crash if [you switch to ReadLine and] the user types non numeric characters

Comment: Thanks a lot. So simple I would never have guessed... I'm just starting C# and am not used to the syntax or frameworks. I'm used to simpler languages like Swift and actually, I haven't done much coding in a while so I've gotten rusty :p Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ReadLine` instead of `Read`.